# Easiest Way to Convert JSON to CSV (Including arrays to fields)

Tags: javascript, json, csv, parse-platform, export-to-csv

I'm trying to convert my parse.com json data into a csv file, except I have a column of type array, and would like each number within each array to be saved within it's own field.

[image]

What's the easiest way to do this using the command line or javascript?

I've tried several online converters but they fail because my data is too large. I'm mainly looking for an answer from someone who has converted parse data to the csv format successfully.

Comment: You don't show any JSON in your question. Please show a (reasonably brief) sample input and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: @nnnnnn Parse allows you to export your data as JSON. I'm having trouble finding an easy way to convert it to CSV. Most online converters fail bc it's really large (83mb)

Comment: I think it is all up to you: Json has 6 primitives (string, number, object,  array, true, false, and null) How you want to serialize them into csv values, it is all up to you!

Answer (score 0):

Yow might want to use a script, python or php, parse the data in batches, and also write the file in batches of lines by retaining the number of line at some point ( in any case when script fails ) and go back and write from that line. A quick pseudo-code example. based on your attachment

If your json it's formatted line by line :

Read file , 10 lines at a time

```
batch = 1000 // sample
current = 0
while (current<batch) 

for each line :
   json_decode() -> create csv string "1,2,3,3.." etc,
   write line by appending to file 
   save line number

   current++
end for

endwhile
```